# Outputting link with URLs based on database entries

Tags: php, security

Is this output safe against XSS and the other attacks or no ?

```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
   $output .= '
  <a href="categories/topics.php?cat_id='. htmlspecialchars($row['cat_id']).'">'.htmlspecialchars($row['cat_name']).'</a>';
    }
   echo $output;
```

Comment: This question appears to be a follow-up to [this answer](/a/165130/9357).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like you are not really looking for a code review, but rather looking for advice around security on a very specific piece of code.  Any answer that would be impossible to give without understanding full context within which this brief coded snippet exists.

Comment: @MikeBrant Asking specifically for security review is not off-topic as far as I know. I do agree that more context is needed, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems fine.

*Technically* speaking, the `cat_id` is part of a URL, and URL components should be [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).  Therefore, it should be `htmlspecialchars(urlencode($row['cat_id']))`.  However, if you are certain that the `cat_id` will be an integer, then there is practically no point in calling either `urlencode()` or `htmlspecialchars()` on it, since digits are not considered special characters in either URLs or in HTML.

Therefore, you could take a shortcut and simplify it to

```
'<a href="categories/topics.php?cat_id=' . $row['cat_id'] . '">' . htmlspecialchars($row['cat_name']) . '</a>'
```